# iOS Core Data + iCloud error for addPersistentStoreWithType: You don’t have permission to save the file “store” in the folder

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, core-data-migration, ubiquity

I've created a Core Data project from scratch, the only change I made is that where the persistent coordinator is adding a store, I'm providing a NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey option:

```
coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: [NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey : "coreDataiCloudTestStore"])
```

and I'm inserting and saving a new managed object at launch.

When at launch there is no iCloud account logged in, no problems. While the app is running, I'm logging into iCloud and going back to the app. I'm getting this error: You don’t have permission to save the file “store” in the folder, operation not permitted:

> CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite
>   configuration:PF_DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_NAME
>   URL:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9032B2BC-BE8B-42C9-A9CC-EF3E01AA6F2B/Documents/SingleViewCoreData.sqlite
>   options:{
>       NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey = coreDataiCloudTestStore;
>       PFUbiquitySetupSynchronousSideLoadKey = 1; }
>
> **... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “store” in the folder**
>   “380E290C-97F9-4DC3-9B3C-43322FCA455D”."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9032B2BC-BE8B-42C9-A9CC-EF3E01AA6F2B/Documents/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/mobile~C5A2ECE3-1AB9-45FA-9C15-037DCCA054DE/coreDataiCloudTestStore/380E290C-97F9-4DC3-9B3C-43322FCA455D/store,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x1453f430 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1
>   "Operation not permitted"}} with userInfo dictionary {
>       NSFilePath = "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9032B2BC-BE8B-42C9-A9CC-EF3E01AA6F2B/Documents/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/mobile~C5A2ECE3-1AB9-45FA-9C15-037DCCA054DE/coreDataiCloudTestStore/380E290C-97F9-4DC3-9B3C-43322FCA455D/store";
>       NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 \"Operation not permitted\""; }
>
> PFUbiquitySwitchboardEntry containerIdentifierChanged::
>   CoreData: Ubiquity:  **Error loading new temporary coordinator after
>   account change with options** { {
>       NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey = coreDataiCloudTestStore; } } and URL
>   file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9032B2BC-BE8B-42C9-A9CC-EF3E01AA6F2B/Documents/SingleViewCoreData.sqlite
>   and error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "**You don’t have
>   permission to save the file “store” in the folder**
>   “380E290C-97F9-4DC3-9B3C-43322FCA455D”."
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9032B2BC-BE8B-42C9-A9CC-EF3E01AA6F2B/Documents/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/mobile~C5A2ECE3-1AB9-45FA-9C15-037DCCA054DE/coreDataiCloudTestStore/380E290C-97F9-4DC3-9B3C-43322FCA455D/store,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x1453f430 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1
>   "Operation not permitted"}}

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

- Probably this is due to the options that you pass in when adding persistent store,
- It happens when you don't let the core data handles the rebuilding icloud-enabled persistent store,
- You must enable the NSPersistentStoreRebuildFromUbiquitousContentOption flag in the options

  **Look at the apple doc**
  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud/UsingSQLiteStoragewithiCloud.html

**Rebuilding from iCloud**

> To remove local data and start fresh with the existing records in iCloud, pass the NSPersistentStoreRebuildFromUbiquitousContentOption option with a value of @YES when you add your iCloud-enabled persistent store to the persistent store coordinator. Include any iCloud options you usually include.

Comment: Is there a solution that will keep existing data if iCloud is enabled later?